# Raising a customized error/exception

Tags: exception, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I'm playing around with Pharo, and would like to raise a customized error/exception/something, but I've got no idea how.
I've browsed the relevant (I think) chapters of "Pharo by Example" and "Deep into Pharo"; but couldn't make heads or tails about it - it seems way above the level that I need...

I've got a setter for a variable, and would like to raise an error/exception if the input isn't an Integer:

```
    MyClass >> someVariable: anInteger
       anInteger isInteger
          ifFalse: [ self SomehowProtestLoadly - the part I don't know how to do ].
       someVariable := anInteger
```

Just aborting or exiting would be sufficient... but if possible, I'd like to do it with a bit more "flare" - and in a more explainatory way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to just signal a generic error:

```
someVariable: anInteger
  anInteger isInteger
    ifFalse: [self error: 'must be an Integer'].
  someVariable := anInteger
```

Now, if you want to signal a specific error, do the following:

1. Create a subclass of `Error`, say, `NonIntegerArgument`
2. Write your code like this

   ```
   someVariable: anInteger
     anInteger isInteger
       ifFalse: [NonIntegerArgument signal: 'must be an Integer'].
     someVariable := anInteger
   ```
3. For handling this exception do the following

   ```
   [myObject someVariable: self value]
     on: NonIntegerArgument
     do: [:ex | self handleException: ex]
   ```

Note that your exception could provide more information, say the actual argument that was sent. To do this add an instance variable to your `NonIntegerArgument` class, namely, `argument`. Add a getter and a setter for it. Then

```
NonIntegerArgument class >> #signal: aString argument: anObject
  ^self new
    argument: anObject;
    signal: aString
```

and use it this way

```
someVariable: anInteger
  anInteger isInteger
    ifFalse: [
      NonIntegerArgument
        signal: 'must be an Integer'
        argument: anInteger].
  someVariable := anInteger
```

Now, the `ex` variable will be able to respond with the `argument` of the offending message.

Comment: Note that the string `'must be an Integer'` is generic enough to be encoded as a default message in `NonIntegerArgument` class rather than repeated at each client. The option for passing a client specific String can eventually be usefull or not, up to OP to decide.

Comment: @aka.nice Good point. Indeed, once you have a specific class for your exception, you can add a lot more of default behavior moving code from the client to the exception object.